# .Net Core MVC Client - Authentication over JWT service

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I have two projects, one is the API, the other one is the Client to consume the API. Both are .net core 3.1. The API project has been developed inspired by this post:

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/06/15/net-5-api-jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens#users-controller-cs

and it has JWT Authentication with refresh token and some methods with Authorize attribute.

My problems starts in the Client project. The API projects emits access token and the client should use it accessing the protected API.

I can authenticated in the API, but when the client receives token (access token and refresh token), it store it in authentication cookie and in the refresh token cookie.

My doubts are:

- Is this approach correct?
- how can i manage that the access token expires and use the refresh token to get a new one? Do cookies need to be regenerated?
- In future development i will add Facebook auth and client auth.

If is needed more details or some implementation let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set the cookie expiration to the same date as the token, so that they both expire at the same time.

Comment: @abusco ok, and when the cookie expires what appens? I don't need to redirect to login page, but insted use the refresh token in order to obtain new access_token and generate new cookie.